# What is CAS authentication?

Tags: java, cas

What is CAS authentication?

Can anybody provide some tutorial or example on CAS authentication implemented in Java?

Actually i want an example where i can use filters and a specific servlet which will handle CAS authentication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CAS (Central Authentication Service) came out of the CS dept at Yale now a JA-SIG project

There is a nicely doc'd example on their wiki which shows the filters in use at

https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Using+CAS+with+Java

Answer (score 5):

CAS is a free and open-source project sponsored by a non-profit organization called JASIG.  It’s used to authenticate users to a system (generally by username/password) and provides other capabilities.  JASIG offers this software for free for other organizations/companies/individuals/etc to configure and deploy on their own servers.  The organization that deploys CAS on their servers is responsible for supporting their local instance.

For step-by-step process, go through the link

https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Demo